# Solana multiple spl tokens transfer python

Tags: spl-token, solana-cli, python

I managed to send some `USDC-dev` token on the devnet with the following code.
Is there a way to send more than 1 transaction with something like `Transaction.add()`

Here is the working code for 1 transaction

```
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from spl.token.client import Token
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
from solders.keypair import Keypair
from solders.system_program import TransferParams, transfer
from solana.transaction import Transaction

mint = Pubkey.from_string(
    "Gh9ZwEmdLJ8DscKNTkTqPbNwLNNBjuSzaG9Vp2KGtKJr"
)  # eg: https://solscan.io/token/FpekncBMe3Vsi1LMkh6zbNq8pdM6xEbNiFsJBRcPbMDQ**
program_id = Pubkey.from_string(
    "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"
)  # eg: https://solscan.io/account/**TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA**

privkey = "6614rQjZYrcUL8YtNQ8vcf.......VM8hJwgMPnSPdBRGHSxxroJLn"
key_pair = Keypair.from_base58_string(privkey)

solana_client = Client("https://api.devnet.solana.com")
spl_client = Token(
    conn=solana_client, pubkey=mint, program_id=program_id, payer=key_pair
)

source = Pubkey.from_string("BAPkhTqGe4Squ8hH71QzixhTcfhJv7Lb8SvV7To5gzPg")
dest = Pubkey.from_string("3ApghjTLzyAfBvq9z1kQkfTp5puoZHsKZZ9ziwBvR8T1")

try:
    source_token_account = (
        spl_client.get_accounts_by_owner(
            owner=source, commitment=None, encoding="base64"
        )
        .value[0]
        .pubkey
    )
    
except:
    source_token_account = spl_client.create_associated_token_account(
        owner=source, skip_confirmation=False, recent_blockhash=None
    )
    
try:
    dest_token_account = (
        spl_client.get_accounts_by_owner(owner=dest, commitment=None, encoding="base64")
        .value[0]
        .pubkey
    )
    
except:
    dest_token_account = spl_client.create_associated_token_account(
        owner=dest, skip_confirmation=False, recent_blockhash=None
    )

amount = 10

txn = Transaction()

transaction = spl_client.transfer(
    source=source_token_account,
    dest=dest_token_account,
    owner=key_pair,
    amount=int(float(amount) * 100000),
    multi_signers=None,
    opts=None,
    recent_blockhash=None,
)

print(transaction)
```

Answer (score 1):

Certainly! The `txn` in your example is actually a `SendTransactionResp` after you call `transfer` on the `spl_client`, and it's doing the work for you of constructing and sending the transaction. You can see its definition at https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/15a87982d91f037b53197e4d6cb73bde397eee10/src/spl/token/client.py#L354

In your case, you'll want to construct a transaction and add multiple instructions to it, ie:

```
txn = Transaction(fee_payer=key_pair.pubkey()).add(
            spl_token.transfer(
                spl_token.TransferParams(
                    program_id=program_id,
                    source=source_token_account,
                    dest=dest_token_account,
                    owner=key_pair.pubkey(),
                    amount=amount,
                    signers=[],
                )
            )
        ).add(
            spl_token.transfer(
                spl_token.TransferParams(
                    program_id=program_id,
                    source=source_token_account,
                    dest=dest_token_account,
                    owner=key_pair.pubkey(),
                    amount=amount,
                    signers=[],
                )
            )
        )
solana_client.send_transaction(txn, key_pair, opts=opts, recent_blockhash=recent_blockhash)
```

This was lifted from the implementation for `transfer` at https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/15a87982d91f037b53197e4d6cb73bde397eee10/src/spl/token/core.py#L281, and has not been compiled or tested, so there may be issues.