# how i can add 20 instructions in a single transaction?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js

I want to send an airdrop of my token to 20 wallts in one transaction ( 20 instructions in one transcation)
I need code python that support my case,
Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

To transfer multiple times in one transaction in Python check out this question that explains exactly how to do it: [Solana multiple spl tokens transfer python](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6615/solana-multiple-spl-tokens-transfer-python)

Note that to transfer to *20* different addresses in one transaction should work, but if you're doing 30 or more you might start running into errors as transactions are limited to [1232 bytes at most](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/9754/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-solana-transaction/9755#9755) and one Solana pubkey is 32 bytes large. Without any additional overhead from e.g. other accounts and instruction data we'd fit at most `1232 / 32 = 38.5 => 38` different recipients in one transaction, however accounting for additional overhead the real number is probably in the low 30s, so keep this in mind if you try this same approach for more than 20 and run into issues.