# What is the maximum size of a Solana transaction?

Tags: transactions

Some transactions fail to execute/build due to being too large, so what's the maximum size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question to help others:

Taking from the [Solana docs](https://docs.solana.com/proposals/versioned-transactions#problem):

> Messages transmitted to Solana validators must not exceed the IPv6 MTU size to ensure fast and reliable network transmission of cluster info over UDP. Solana's networking stack uses a conservative MTU size of 1280 bytes which, after accounting for headers, leaves 1232 bytes for packet data like serialized transactions.

i.e. the maximum size of a transaction is 1232 bytes.